# IOS programmatically move apps into a folder at home screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS, I have a question which is

I have few separate apps. After installation of these apps. It show as different apps icon in the home screen and I have to manually move these apps together to form a folder with apps contains. Do we have any ways to make these apps install and form a folder automatically by programmatically ways?

If yes, can show me how it can be done?

Sorry for my lousy English.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you can only do it on jailbreaked device.

Comment: oh~?...Is it?...thanks for the response.

Comment: You cannot do it except in jailbreak device. Developers have been restricted to play with springboard by Apple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this on a non jailbroken iOS device. Each app is only responsible for what's going on inside the app. There are some exceptions to this (you can run certain logics in the background, subscribe to be woken up as a result of a certain notification, or provide an extension for the user to add to their Today screen or use via other apps), but you have no control over the user's home screen. Positioning the icons there is in the sole responsibility of your user.